# Question about the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration over subintervals: $\int_J f(s) dZ(s)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stieltjes-integral

-**Proposition**: Let $I \subset \mathbb{R} $ be an interval and $Z: I \to \mathbb{R}$ monotonically increasing and rightside continuous. If

1. $I=(a,b)$ or $I=(a,b]$ then there exist a unique measure $m_Z$ on $\mathcal{B}(I)$ (Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra on $I$) such that $$m_Z((s,t])=Z(t)-Z(s)\;, s\leq t.$$
2. $I=[a,b)$ or $I=[a,b]$ and $Z(a)\geq0$ then there exist a unique measure $m_Z$ on $\mathcal{B}(I)$ such that $$m_Z([a,t])=Z(t)\;, t\geq a$$

-**First Question**: Is it correct that $\{(s,t]|s\leq t, s,t \in I\}$ induces the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(I)$ in the case that $I=(a,b)$ or $I=(a,b]$ but not if $I=[a,b)$ or $I=[a,b]$?

-**Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral**: For a $\mathcal{B}(I)$-measurable function $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ we can define the Lebesgue-stieltjes integral as $$\int_I f(s) dZ(s):=\int_I f(s) m_Z(s) ds$$ if the Lebesgue integral on the right hand side is defined.

-**2.Question:** Sometimes we want to integrate over a subinterval $J\subset I$. From the defintion of the Lebesgue integral this is defined as $\int_J f(s) dZ(s):=\int_J f|_J(s) \;m_Z|_{\mathcal{B}(J)}(s)$ (or equivalently: $\int_J f(s) dZ(s):=\int_I f(s) \mathbb{1}_J\;m_Z(s)$). But do we obtain the same result if we instead consider the measure $m_{Z|_J}$ on $\mathcal{B}(J)$ that is induced by the restriction $Z|_J: J \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e $$\int_J f|_J(s) dZ|_J(s)\;\;\quad?$$
Equivalently I can formulate the question as follows: Is $m_{Z|_J}=m_Z|_{\mathcal{B}(J)}$ on $\mathcal{B}(J)$?

-**Considerations for the 2. Question**: This is true if $J=(a,b)$ or $J=(a,b]$ no matter what form $I$ has: $$m_{Z|_J}((s,t])= Z|_J(t)-Z|J(s)=Z(t)-Z(s)=m_Z((s,t])=m_Z|_{\mathcal{B}(J)}((s,t]).$$ But if $J=[a,b]$ or $J=[a,b)$ this isn't generally true: Let for example $I=[\tilde{a},\tilde{b}]$ then $$m_{Z|_J}([a,t])= Z|_J(t)=Z(t)=m_Z([\tilde{a},t])=m_Z([\tilde{a},a))+m_Z([a,t])=m_Z([\tilde{a},a))+m_Z|_{\mathcal{B}(J)}([a,t]) \neq m_Z|_{\mathcal{B}(J)}([a,t])$$ if $m_Z([\tilde{a},a))>0$.

Comment: You've dropped something in your definition of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. $m_Z$ is a set function, but in your definition, you are using it as a function on the elements of $I$. That makes no sense. $m_Z$ is a measure. You should know how Lebesgue measure with respect to an arbitrary measure is expressed. This is not it.

Comment: Second answer: $m_{Z|_J}([a,t])\ne Z|_J(t)$. Instead $m_{Z|_J}([a,t])= Z|_J(t) - Z|_J(a)$

Comment: @PaulSinclair I didn't used $m_Z$ as a function of elements of $I$. But as in the Proposition mentioned there exist a unique measure $m_z:\mathcal{B}(I)\to [0,\infty]$ with $m_z([a,t])=Z(t)$ for all $t \in I$ if $I$ is closed on the right and $Z\geq 0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair to your first answer: So $\{(s,t]|s,t\in I\}$ induces the borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $I$ if $I$ is open on the left and $\{[a,t]|t \in I\}$ induces $\mathcal{B}(I)$ if $I$ is closed on the left?

Comment: I quote (look up above, and you will see it in your post): $$\int_I f(s) dZ(s):=\int_I f(s) m_Z(s) ds$$ You have $m_Z(s)$, right next to $f(s)$. $f$ is a function of the elements of $I$. $s$ therefore has to an element of $I$. Therefore "$m_Z(s)$" is you applying  $m_Z$ to an element of $I$, even though $m_Z$ is a function of sets, not elements of $I$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah ok, I guess this is just a question about notation. I also write $\int_{[a,b]} f(x) d\lambda(x)$ instead of $\int_{[a,b]} f(x) d\lambda$

Comment: Both are bad notation, particularly the first, which, again, makes no sense at all. Concerning your other question. I admit I was mistaken. I had overlooked that $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complementation. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{(s,t]\mid s,t \in I\}$ includes the sets $[x, b] = \bigcap_n (x-\frac 1n, b]$, and therefore $[a, x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$. From there is easy to see that it contains all subintervals of $I$ and so must be $\mathcal B(I)$. Similar remarks occur for $\{(s,t)\mid s,t \in I\}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair First of all thanks for your effort! I guess in your last comment is still a mistake since  $a-\frac{1}{n} \notin I=[a,b]$ and therefore the intervals $\bigcap_n (a-\frac{1}{n},b] \notin I$. I also wondering about the notation which is the common one used in every book.

Comment: I never said anything about $a - \frac 1n$. Note in fact that I only claimed to show $[x,b]$ is in the algebra for $x \in (a,b)$. $x = a$ is not included. However, notice that I started by pointing out my earlier mistake: $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complementation. Now. what is $I \setminus [x, b]$ when $I = [a,b]$? If your book uses $d\lambda(x)$, that is a bit bad, but also quite common. It misleads about what is going on with $\lambda$ and is only used because of its resemblance to Leibniz notation. But $m_Z(s)$ is much worse. It outright lies about the nature of this integration.

Comment: There often is a function that could be used where you used $m_Z(s)$. That is the Rado-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dm_Z}{d\lambda}$. But that is not $m_Z$, and only exists for some $Z$ (I believe when $Z$ is continuous, but I may be forgetting something again). But the L.S. integral, which is actually defined by $\int_I f(x)\,dm_Z$ (and there even I use the $dm_Z$ notation despite its short-comings) exists for all $Z$ as described, not just the continuous ones.